# WIF Enable WCF Application

Tags: wcf, wif, claims-based-identity, ws-federation, ws-trust

I'm a newbie in STS. I'm trying to WIF enable WCF application, so i found this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Claims-Aware-Web-Service-1d55facc) but i can not make it run.

I'm getting the following error:

An unexpected exception occured.
Server stack trace: em System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CardSpaceShim.GetCardSpaceImplementationDll()...

Could anyone point me out the solution. I've searched everywhere for an answer and nothing.

Comment: You're using an outdated article/example.   Anyway, at least post the code that's throwing the error and the whole error message, otherwise it's a guessing game that no one has time for.

Answer (score 0):

Cardspace is an extremely old Microsoft product that has been depracted for years.

Try:

sc.ClientCredentials.SupportInteractive = false;

as in:

- [WCF : Different flavours of ADFS](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013_04_01_archive.html)
- [ADFS : WCF web service](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/adfs-wcf-web-service.html)